# How to use terraform import with resource configuration

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

Prior to terraform import, I have defined:

```
# instance.tf

resource "aws_instance" "appserver" {

}
```

Then I ran: `terraform import aws_instance.appserver <instance-id>` and went smoothly, which I can see the imported ec2 resource by using terraform show. However, the mystery to me is to "transfer" this existing terraform state into the terraform config (instance.tf above) so that I can manage it as an Infrastructure as a Code (or at least that how I understood it). I added the ami and instance_type keys and their corresponding values but every time I issue `terraform plan`, terraform seems to want to "replace" my existing instance.

1) Why is terraform want to replace that instance?

2) How can I "transfer" the instance's terraform state into the config? (is this possible?)

3) For you guys seasoned veterans, how were you guys able to manage an existing aws infrastructure in terraform?

Comment: The plan would have explained the reason for the replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, terraform wants to replace your instance because terraform didn't do the 'link' you expected between the resource configuration and the current existing instance.

Terraform official documentation: (https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/index.html)

> The current implementation of Terraform import can only import
>   resources into the state. It does not generate configuration. A future
>   version of Terraform will also generate configuration.
>
> Because of this, prior to running terraform import it is necessary to
>   write manually a resource configuration block for the resource, to
>   which the imported object will be mapped.
>
> While this may seem tedious, it still gives Terraform users an avenue
>   for importing existing resources. A future version of Terraform will
>   fully generate configuration, significantly simplifying this process.

After understanding the written above, I would use the following steps:

1. First, write your terraform resource configuration. Should look like this:

   ```
   resource "aws_instance" "example" {
        # ...instance configuration...
   }
   ```
2. `terraform import aws_instance.example i-abcd1234` in order to import existing infrastructure to your **state** and attach it to the resource configuration you've created above.

Detailed source for more: https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/usage.html

Answer (score 1):

Terraform 1.5 [introduced](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-1-5-brings-config-driven-import-and-checks) [import blocks](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/import) for "config-driven import". This allows [`plan`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/plan)/[`apply`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/apply) operations to seamlessly manage the state of your preexisting infrastructure if you simply provide the [import ID](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/import#import-id) values as part of your configuration.

Example import block:

```
import {
  to = aws_instance.example
  id = "i-abcd1234"
}
```

To assist with config generation, Terraform now offers [`terraform plan -generate-config-out=PATH`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/plan#generate-config-out-path). In the tutorial [Import Terraform Confiuration](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/state/state-import), importing existing resources is described as a five-step process including...

> 3. Run `terraform plan` to review the import plan and optionally generate configuration for the resources.
> 4. Prune generated configuration to only the required arguments.
> 5. Apply the configuration to bring the resource into your Terraform state file.

The tutorial includes this associated recommendation...

> We recommend that you prune the generated configuration to only required arguments and arguments whose values differ from defaults, to reduce the size of your configuration.

Comment: Note: This new feature has limitations: [Missing/limited workspace/variable support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76486088/86967); `terraform plan` fails if any `import` resource id doesn't exist (requires pruning _after_ deletion of imported resources); ...

Comment: Maybe the best way to isolate the import from 'apply' (although deprecated and undocumented): `terraform refresh`