# How to manage Terraform import IDs separately per workspace?

Tags: terraform, terraform-import, terraform-workspace

Terraform 1.5 [introduced](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-1-5-brings-config-driven-import-and-checks) [import blocks](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/import) for "config-driven import". This allows [`plan`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/plan)/[`apply`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/apply) operations to seamlessly manage the state of your preexisting infrastructure if you simply provide the [import ID](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/import#import-id) values as part of your configuration.

Example import block:

```
import {
  to = aws_instance.example
  id = "i-abcd1234"
}
```

This appears to be a huge step forward for tasks and workflows in which the state is not already under management by a [Terraform state backend](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/state/backends)[<sup>1</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73327454/86967). However, when using [Workspaces](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/state/workspaces) to differentiate between deployment instances, *each config resource will have a unique ID per workspace*. It isn't clear that there's a clean way to specify these unique ID values.

How can we specify unique ID values per workspace?

Comment: The approach I've landed on is code generation.

Answer (score 2):

> How can we specify unique ID values per workspace?

This is currently not possible as far as I can tell, because you cannot use variables in the `import` block. I've opened a GitHub issue for this https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/33383.

There's also another open issue https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/33380 which proposes a workspace parameter for the block, which if implemented would effectively be an alternative to my proposal.

Comment: Enabling the `workspace` intrinsic does seem like the path of least resistance even though this seems like one of the blocks where enabling variable resolution may prove problematic.

Comment: @MattSchuchard uhm yeah perhaps, but that would first of all lead to quite the code duplication, and then introduce yet another special case where the general constructs of the language cannot be applied..

Comment: I was referring to your answer that is probably the best possible information at this time (ergo the upvote), and specifically the second cited issue with a proposed resolution, and adding details. I am unsure to what you are referring in your comment.

Comment: @MattSchuchard all I am saying is that if I had to choose between what I proposed in 33383 vs what is proposed 33380, I'd choose what I proposed